How to build a Max for Live synth that can do a full range continuous frequency sweep?
I want to be able to generate simple low and high tones from various parts of the human-audible frequency range. These will vary over time, and one obstacle I am running into using Live's Operator synth is that there are two knobs rather than one. There is a Freq knob and a Multi knob to act as a multiplier of that base frequency.

Note the bottom left controls. "Fixed" frequencies are being used, specified by the Freq and Multi knobs.
With this schema one can work with precision on any single section of the frequency spectrum at a time, but transitioning across these "break-points" where the Multi knob must be tweaked is a real hinderance for the kind of automation I'm trying to do.
The 5 frequency ranges allowed by the Multi knob:

0.01 Hz ( 10Hz * 0.001 )
to
2 Hz (2000Hz * 0.001)


0.1 Hz ( 10Hz * 0.01 )
to
20 Hz (2000Hz * 0.01)


1 Hz ( 10Hz * 0.1 )
to
200 Hz (2000Hz * 0.1)


10 Hz ( 10Hz * 1 )
to
2000 Hz (2000Hz * 1)


100 Hz ( 10Hz * 10 )
to
20000 Hz (2000Hz * 10)

I don't believe any of the built-in Live synths can seamlessly sweep across the entire frequency range. So I would like to put together a simple tone-based synth in Max for Live instead.
I don't have experience building custom synths in Max for Live, as I mostly use presets. But maybe this little project can be an opportunity to start digging into M4L's capabilities. How can I construct a synth in M4L that can take any float number as its frequency value, and allow that value to be automated across the audible range? As an additional requirement, this must be compatible with Ableton Live 9 Suite. Thanks.

What about using a resonant 24 dB/oct filter in a synth plugin as the oscillator and just sweeping the cutoff?

@ToddWilcox A filter sweep won't give the desired result. The oscillator pitch itself needs to change. But I really appreciate your suggestion - especially since it spurred me to search one more time with different keywords, and I think I've now found a solution. I'll post an answer in a moment.

You can make resonant filters into oscillators. So it’s no longer a filter at all, it’s an oscillator where the frequency is controlled by the cutoff knob instead of the keyboard.

@ToddWilcox Interesting... I encourage you to post an answer if you don't mind. Please include screenshots if possible.

Mentalist's answer gives you what you need, but in case you were interested in how to build it yourself in M4L, I'll detail it (its a good simple project to start learning M4L, in my opinion!)
I don't have a M4L license anymore, so I can't take my own screenshots, but I'll link some timestamped parts of a youtube video that does something similar (no affiliation, and note the video isn't doing exactly what you want).

Start with the "Max Instrument" preset (youtube ref)

Add a slider object (Max reference)

Set the minimum value, size (this is the range of the slider, confusingly), orientation as desired
do this in the inspector  ("i" icon on the right side)
you could also use other inputs, like e.g. the "live.dial" object


Add a "cycle~" object. This generates a sine wave audio output, at the whatever frequency it gets as an input value (youtube ref)

Wire the slider to the cycles~ object's left input

Wire the cycle~ object's output to the left & right audio outputs (the "plugout~" device) (youtube ref)

Delete the midiin (you don't care about the midi input)


You should have something that looks like this (but actually in M4L):

And there you have it, a slider that controls a sine wave!
If you want to delve deeper into M4L, ableton has made a nice playlist of instructional videos, and there's plenty of books and stuff too.

Thank you! I'm marking your answer as the accepted one, because I think info on how to construct a device is most valuable. The Test Tone Generator answer I posted is handy for someone in a fix who needs to make a tone quickly, but as for getting an "under the hood" understanding, your answer offers more. As I was following your explanation I ended up doing a few things differently, for example using the Max for Live Objects slider because it can be automated. Maybe I'll share my configuration. In any case, it's working as needed and it's empowering that I can expand the functionality too.

I've been playing around with M4L since following your advice! It's pretty fun. I got stuck trying to to some simple math with frequencies and posted a question about the “+” object. It just occurred to me that you might be a good candidate to answer it, if you feel so inclined.

@Mentalist there might be a way in the inspector to set the "plain" slider as being able to be automated, but I can't be sure without max in front of me. Make sure to poke around in the inspector to learn more about all the things you can adjust in different objects!

This Max for Live device does the trick:
Test Tone Generator by tr3b
The output range is 0Hz〜10kHz, so not the entire audible range, but I don't expect to need anything higher than that.
Live version used: 9.7, Max version used: 7.3.3

The Freq value can be automated, so I expect this will do everything I need.
